# How to find all references of a selected module in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way/shortcut to quickly search for all references of a selected module?

By selected I mean, if I select a file in the explorer view, or if the focus is set on the file in the active editor. Ideally it should be something that is as easy as
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, but the latter only selects symbols *inside* a file.

I could iterate over all of the exports using the above shortcut, but what if the file has several exports? Also, the results are not displayed all at once.

**Here's an example:**

Say I wanted to find the file **`array.ts`**, my current workaround would be to search for a Regular Expression pattern — `from ["'].*array["']` — which works, but I would like to know if there is a faster way?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, seems not possbile atm.! My workaround is to bind a regex "from [\"'].*/placeholder[\"']" to a keybinding, so I don't have to type it manually when I want to search a referenced module

Comment: ok, I created feature request:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66150

Answer (score 0):

The issue ticket which [@Dzenly](/users/4053283) opened ([Context menu 'Find all references' on files from file explorer.
#66150](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66150)) was closed as completed by another issue ticket: [Enable TS 4.2 features #115255](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115255).

You can now use the `TypeScript: Find File References` command to find file refereces for the TypeScript file in the currently focused editor tab, or right click an item in the Explorer view and use the "Find File References" action. If you want to make a keybinding, the command ID is `typescript.findAllFileReferences`.