# Find all `require`s or `import`s of a Node.js module in VSCode?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have a Node.JS project in VSCode 1.29.1. I'd like to see all places where a module is `require`d or `import`ed. Is there a good way to do this, or an extension? When I click "find all references" on the symbol that's `module.export`ed, it only lists references in that file.

As a workaround, I've been doing "find in project" with the regex search `require\(.*moduleName.*\)`.

Comment: how about doing cmd + shift + f and then typing and searching it the line `const whatever` ? Although I know this approach have many drawbacks but maybe a work around? Ps: I am also following this post.

Comment: Yep, that's another thing I try! But sometimes this codebase names imports inconsistently. :)

Comment: I doubt, there is no other solution (yet). A few days ago, I posted exactly this- no answer yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267307/how-to-find-all-references-of-a-selected-module-in-vs-code  .

Comment: @ford04 I wrote an answer to that question. See if you deem it worthy of an upvote/accept.